# How to enable showing a custom adaptive card sent from Microsoft Flow in Outlook Mobile app for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, outlook, adaptive-cards, power-automate

we are using [amdesigner.azurewebsite](https://amdesigner.azurewebsites.net/)s to design a custom adaptive card to be sent through Microsoft flow to our organization members for PO approvals. The JSON code for the card is generated from the designer and the originator id was generated and approved from Actionable Message Developer Dashboard.

We trigger the flow to send the email containing the actionable message card, it shows and works perfectly in Microsoft Outlook desktop and OWA (web outlook accessed from a desktop web browser). However, when we check the same email from Outlook iOS and Android Mobile app and OWA in a mobile web browser, the email shows empty (the card does not render at all).

We already contacted Microsoft support (Office 365, Flow and iOS in-app) and all of them were saying that this is outside their scope and keeps redirecting us back and forth from one support portal to another, with no resolution whatsoever.

```
<script type="application/adaptivecard+json">
    {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "padding": "none",
        "originator": "*******************************",
        "body": [
            {
                "type": "Container",
                "style": "emphasis",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                        "columns": [
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                        "size": "Medium",
                                        "weight": "Bolder",
                                        "text": "PURCHASE ORDER APPROVAL",
                                        "color": "Dark",
                                        "wrap": true
                                    }
                                ],
                                "width": "stretch",
                                "style": "default",
                                "backgroundImage": null,
                                "bleed": false
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Image",
                                        "horizontalAlignment": "Right",
                                        "url": "https://.....",
                                        "height": "70px",
                                        "altText": "GTS Logo"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "width": "auto",
                                "style": "default",
                                "backgroundImage": "https://www.haceonline.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/light-gray-solid-color-background-300x150.jpg",
                                "bleed": false
                            }
                        ],
                        "style": null,
                        "bleed": false
                    }
                ],
                "backgroundImage": null,
                "bleed": false
            },
            {
                "type": "Container",
                "padding": {
                    "top": "none",
                    "left": "default",
                    "bottom": "default",
                    "right": "default"
                },
                "items": [
                    {
                        "type": "Container",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "ColumnSet",
                                "spacing": "Large",
                                "separator": true,
                                "columns": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Column",
                                        "items": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                                "size": "Medium",
                                                "text": "Requested by **Rawad Farhat**",
                                                "wrap": true,
                                                "spacing": "None"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                                "spacing": "None",
                                                "text": "rawad.farhat@gtslb.com",
                                                "isSubtle": true
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "width": "stretch",
                                        "style": null,
                                        "backgroundImage": null,
                                        "bleed": false
                                    }
                                ],
                                "style": null,
                                "bleed": false
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                "spacing": "Medium",
                                "text": "**The following Purchase Order has been submitted for approval:**",
                                "wrap": true
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "FactSet",
                                "facts": [
                                    {
                                        "title": "Requested Date:",
                                        "value": "06 Aug 2019"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "Purchase Order:",
                                        "value": "19000001-OP-00210"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "Container",
                                "style": null,
                                "backgroundImage": null,
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                                        "style": null,
                                        "columns": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "Column",
                                                "style": null,
                                                "backgroundImage": null,
                                                "items": [
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                        "text": "**Item**",
                                                        "size": "Small",
                                                        "wrap": true
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                                "bleed": false,
                                                "width": "100px"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "type": "Column",
                                                "style": null,
                                                "backgroundImage": null,
                                                "items": [
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                        "text": "**Quantity - Description**",
                                                        "size": "Small",
                                                        "wrap": true
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                                "bleed": false,
                                                "width": "stretch"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "bleed": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                                        "style": null,
                                        "columns": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "Column",
                                                "style": null,
                                                "backgroundImage": null,
                                                "items": [
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                                                        "style": null,
                                                        "columns": [
                                                            {
                                                                "type": "Column",
                                                                "style": null,
                                                                "backgroundImage": null,
                                                                "items": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "Input.Toggle",
                                                                        "id": "itemLine01",
                                                                        "spacing": "None",
                                                                        "title": " ",
                                                                        "value": "false",
                                                                        "validation": null,
                                                                        "wrap": true
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "bleed": false,
                                                                "width": "auto"
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "type": "Column",
                                                                "spacing": "None",
                                                                "style": null,
                                                                "backgroundImage": null,
                                                                "items": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                                        "spacing": "None",
                                                                        "text": "Item",
                                                                        "wrap": true
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "bleed": false,
                                                                "width": "stretch"
                                                            }
                                                        ],
                                                        "bleed": false
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                                "bleed": false,
                                                "width": "100px"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "type": "Column",
                                                "style": null,
                                                "backgroundImage": null,
                                                "items": [
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                                        "text": "Description",
                                                        "size": "Small",
                                                        "wrap": true
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                                "bleed": false,
                                                "width": "stretch"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "bleed": false
                                    }
                                ],
                                "bleed": false
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "ActionSet",
                                "actions": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                                        "title": "Approve",
                                        "card": {
                                            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                                            "style": "emphasis",
                                            "body": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "Input.Text",
                                                    "id": "commentsApprove",
                                                    "placeholder": "Comments (Optional)",
                                                    "isMultiline": true,
                                                    "validation": null
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "actions": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "Action.Http",
                                                    "title": "Submit",
                                                    "method": "POST",
                                                    "url": "https://....",
                                                    "body": "{\"instanceID\": \"instanceID\", \"response\": \"Approve\", \"comments\": \"{{commentsApprove.value}}\" }",
                                                    "headers": [
                                                        {
                                                            "name": "Authorization",
                                                            "value": ""
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                            "name": "Content-Type",
                                                            "value": "application/json"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "backgroundImage": null,
                                            "bleed": false,
                                            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                                        "title": "Reject",
                                        "card": {
                                            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                                            "style": "emphasis",
                                            "body": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "Input.Text",
                                                    "id": "commentsReject",
                                                    "placeholder": "Comments (Optional)",
                                                    "isMultiline": true,
                                                    "validation": null
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "actions": [
                                                {
                                                    "type": "Action.Http",
                                                    "title": "Submit",
                                                    "method": "POST",
                                                    "url": "https://....",
                                                    "body": "{\"instanceID\": \"instanceID\", \"response\": \"Reject\", \"comments\": \"{{commentsReject.value}}\" }",
                                                    "headers": [
                                                        {
                                                            "name": "Authorization",
                                                            "value": ""
                                                        } ,
                                                        {
                                                            "name": "Content-Type",
                                                            "value": "application/json"
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "backgroundImage": null,
                                            "bleed": false,
                                            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "style": null,
                        "backgroundImage": null,
                        "bleed": false
                    }
                ],
                "style": null,
                "backgroundImage": null,
                "bleed": false
            }
        ],
        "version": "1.0",
        "style": null,
        "backgroundImage": "null",
        "bleed": false,
        "actions": null,
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "minHeight": "800px"
    }
    </script>
```

Here is the full adaptive card JSON file that is used in the "send email" action in MS Flow.

One last piece of information, while using [amdesigner](https://amdesigner.azurewebsites.net/) there is a button that sends the card to my email to test viewing it, when we use that button for the same exact adaptive card, it displays fine in outlook mobile.

Please help.

Comment: Actionable messages may not care about this, but your card version should be 1.2 if you're using action sets

Comment: I tried this, changed the version to 1.2 but still the same, email is showing empty in mobile outlook app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the users coming back to this post now - the adaptive cards do not need to be white-listed anymore and should work as is without any intervention from Microsoft side.
Adaptive cards are also supported in dark mode now, so that should not be a blocker anymore.

Answer (score 2):

To all who come through this thread and are facing the same issue, we have found the solution and it is to contact onboardoam@microsoft.com microsoft onboarding team.

They block all adaptive cards that don't go through their white-listing program, to make sure that the cards are formatted correctly and are displaying fine in mobile devices.

In addition, if someone already went through the process and still don't get their card to display in mobile Outlook, probably you have dark mode enable in the app, which is not yet supported for adaptive cards (the color scheme don't auto switch yet). By the team is working on getting it compatible in the near future.